# I need advice to fix my HighLow code in java

Tags: java

Im fairly new to java and im having trouble getting this to loop? The code works fine, its just that after the user guesses correctly the code stops.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Chapter3HighLow {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random random = new Random(); //gives random numbers each time
        int correctNum = random.nextInt(100);
        int NumberOfTries = 0; // tells how many guesses it took

        while (true) {  

            System.out.println("Hi! Please enter a number between 1-100! (if you would like to quit, please press -1)");
            int guess1 = input.nextInt();
            NumberOfTries++; //user enters their guesses

            if (guess1 == (-1)) {
                break; //breaks the loop if the user enters -1
            }

            if(guess1 < correctNum){
                System.out.println("The number inserted is too low!");

            }
            else if(guess1 > correctNum){
                System.out.println("The number inserted is too high!");

            }
            else if(guess1 == correctNum){
                System.out.println("The number you entered was Correct!!");
                System.out.println("It took you " + NumberOfTries + " tries"); // Tells how many tries it  took
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want it to do? Loop over and over again to give the user another change to play?

Comment: move correctNum generation inside your loop.

Comment: @Leonidos No! That would mess everything up! She will need two loops, an outer loop and an inner loop.

Comment: @James yeah, thats exactly what im trying to do, and if they want to quit they can enter -1

Comment: @SeannaWhite If you take a look at the answer I have just posted, I have shown you how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, however, from what I can understand, you are looking to get your game to loop continuously until the user wants to stop playing. So what you are looking for is a method which gives the user a choice whether they want to play again. My suggesting is using `boolean`. The following code demonstrates this for your example:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Chapter3HighLow {
private static boolean playAgain(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String usrInput = "";
    System.out.println("Play again? (Y/N)");
    usrInput = sc.next();
    if(usrInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
        return true;
    }
    else if(usrInput.equalsIgnoreCase("N")){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random random = new Random(); //gives random numbers each time
    int correctNum = random.nextInt(100);
    int NumberOfTries = 0; // tells how many guesses it took
    int guess1 = 0;
    do{
        do{
            System.out.println("Please guess a number between 1-100!");
            guess1 = input.nextInt();
            NumberOfTries++; //user enters their guesses
            if (guess1 == (-1)) {
                break; //breaks the loop if the user enters -1
            }
            if(guess1 < correctNum){
                System.out.println("The number inserted is too low!");
            }
            else if(guess1 > correctNum){
                System.out.println("The number inserted is too high!");
            }
            else if(guess1 == correctNum){
                System.out.println("The number you entered was Correct!!");
                System.out.println("It took you " + NumberOfTries + " tries"); // Tells how many tries it  took
            }
        }while(guess1 != correctNum);
        correctNum = random.nextInt(100);
        NumberOfTries = 0;
    }while(playAgain() == true);
}
}
```

Read more about methods [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

Read more about the `boolean` data type [here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/boolean_values.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your final `else` appears to be missing a `break`. Like

```
else if(guess1 == correctNum){
    System.out.println("The number you entered was Correct!!");
    System.out.println("It took you " + NumberOfTries + " tries");
    break; // <-- add this.
}
```

**or** you might make that the `while` condition. Something like,

```
int guess1 = -1;
while (guess1 != correctNum) {
    System.out.println("Hi! Please enter a number between 1-100! "
        + "(if you would like to quit, please press -1)");
    guess1 = input.nextInt();
    if (guess1 == (-1)) {
        break;
    }
    NumberOfTries++;

    if (guess1 < correctNum) {
        System.out.println("The number inserted is too low!");
    } else if (guess1 > correctNum) {
        System.out.println("The number inserted is too high!");
    } else if (guess1 == correctNum) {
        System.out.println("The number you entered was Correct!!");
        System.out.println("It took you " + NumberOfTries + " tries");
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so i changed the guess1 = input.nextInt(); but now its saying that the thread 'main' hasnt been initialized?

Comment: What else did you change?

Answer (score -1):

Does it really stop after guessing it right ?

[image]